# How to make an AJAX request in Symfony3?

Tags: jquery, symfony

How to make an AJAX request in Symfony3? Can someone explain a step by step rule?

I want to use `$.load()` and `$.ajax()` in Symfony3.

Comment: You're looking for more of a guide to jQuery...when requests are made via AJAX, Symfony treats them as they treat any other page...the only difference is you might want to return a `JsonResponse` and handle it a little differently than a traditional route.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Have you ever done an AJAX request or used Symfony3?

Comment: So what have you tried so far to incorporate Symfony and AJAX?  What sort of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have 3 entities like Country, state & city. I am able to show country, but when i change the country value in select box I want to get state values automatically shown up in state select box and so on for city too.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html should give you what you need

Comment: Way too broad. Edit your question to include the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Furthermore, ajax in symfony3 isn't fundamentally different that ajax in any other php-based application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the setup so far that you can render html in a browser,

put a script block to your view

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('your_route') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {foo: 'bar'},
        success:function(d){
            console.log(d);
        }
    })

</script>
```

et voilá you made an ajax request in symfony3

Comment: For a nice way to expose the routes to the javascript, look into the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but why it's not showing any output, my page on which route goes have some text?

Comment: the code as i posted it just logs the result to the browser console mybe have a look there

Comment: @k0pernikus Do you know if this bundle can be used with Symfony3?

Comment: @Sid Take a look at [FOSJsRoutingBundle's composer.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/master/composer.json), there you'll find `"symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.3||~3.0"`, hence: yes, symfony3 seems to be supported. I haven't tested it though.